# Как скачать zip архив по ссылке с помощью gulp?

Tags: gulp

Пытаюсь скачать и распаковать архив с последней версией wordpress c помощью плагина `gulp-download` и `gulp-decompress`, но на этапе скачивания в консоль постоянно приходит

> undefined%

При этом если перейти по ссылке вручную, скачивание начинается. Вот код:

```
gulp.task("getWP", () => {
       let url ="https://uk.wordpress.org/latest-uk.zip"
       download(url).pipe(decompress()).pipe(dest(project.build.php));
   })
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в плагине. Вместо него использовал [gulp-download2](https://github.com/atomicpages/gulp-download2). Все загрузилось. Правда вместо gulp-decompress нужно будет использовать другой плагин, так как gulp-decompress не поддерживает streams.